# Why is the number of "all time messages" only shown for room owners currently in the room?

Tags: support, bug, chat

In the "Overview" of some of the Stack Exchange chat rooms, the number of "all time messages" is shown for some of the room owners and not shown for the rest.

For example, let's take [The h Bar](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar):

[image]

Here I can see 83.8k for ACuriousMind and 19.2k for DavidZ, and nothing for the rest. For a similar example, check out the [SO Python](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/6/python) room. Is this a bug?

### Update:

[@ACuriousMind pointed out](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48829542#48829542) that:

> The room owners for which the message numbers are shown are exactly
>   the ones that also appear in the list "currently in room" to the
>   right.

Okay, that makes sense now. But I still don't understand why the "all time messages" should be shown only for "currently in room" ROs. Is there any justification for this? Or is this an unintentional design flaw?

Comment: There's nothing special about ROs here. You can see all-time room messages for *everyone* currently in the room, and not for anyone currently not in it. You might rephrase your question to "why can't we see all-time messages in a particular room for every user", for which the answer would probably be "why bother storing all that info".

Comment: @Randal'Thor 1. "You can see all-time room messages for everyone currently in the room, and not for anyone currently not in it." - Not true. Check out the "frequently in room" tab [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/71/the-h-bar). I can see the number for *all* of them although *most* of them are **not** in the room. 2. "why bother storing all that info" - That info is *already* **stored** by the system. You can check out the "all time messages" (in any specific room) of *any* user whenever they visit that room. Why they don't make it always **visible** is something only SE knows.

Comment: For some related discussion, check out [this transcript](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/48829614#48829614).